# How do I solve the error object not found after I created this variable using mutate?

Tags: r, syntax-error, dplyr

I have added a variable that is the sum of all policies for each customer:

```
mhomes %>% mutate(total_policies = rowSums(select(., starts_with("num"))))
```

However, when I now want to use this `total_policies` variable in plots or when using `summary()` it says: Error in summary(total_policies) : object 'total_policies' not found.

I don't understand what I did wrong or what I should do differently here.

Comment: You're likely using `select` in the wrong way. Could you add sample data with `dput(head(mhomes,n))`? You may need to look at `across` and/or the good ol' `mutate_at`.

Comment: I can't use the ```dput(head(mhomes,n))``` because it gives an error. There are 20 variables all starting with num, for example ```num_life``` showing the number of life insurances. The thing I need to do is: Add the variable total_policies, which calculates how many policies  each customer has purchased.

Comment: Try `dput(head(mhomes, 5))` and there should be no error. Then we can try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

May be slightly round about, but feel solves the purpose. Considering **df** is the dataset and it has **customer_id**, **policy_id** and **policy_amount** as variables then the below command should work

req_output = `df %>% group_by(customer_id) %>% summarise (total_policies = sum (policy_amount)`

if you still face the issue, kindly convert to data frame and try plotting

req_output = `as.data.frame(req_output)`